# "This pull request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved."

Tags: git, github

I'm getting that error with a PR, but when I `git status` it says `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

That's on the branch with the PR.

```
On branch pr12
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 23):

`git status` tells you about the state of your **working directory tree** and your **index** (where staged changes live) relative to the latest commit on the current branch. The output you're seeing means that the files on your disk exactly match the latest commit on your branch. That is, there's "nothing to commit".

The message from GitHub is not about *committing*, but about *merging*. GitHub would like to offer you a one-click method to merge this branch into your `master` branch, but it can't, because that merge results in conflicts. Since GitHub doesn't have a way to help you resolve conflicts though the website, it asks you to resolve them on your own machine.

The best way to deal with this situation is to **merge the current master branch into your topic branch locally** and then push the result to GitHub. To do that, do the following:

```
$ git checkout pr12  # If you're not already on pr12
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge origin/master
```

(I'm assuming that the GitHub remote is called `origin`. It typically is, and you probably know if it isn't.)

First we make sure we're on the right branch. Then we make sure we have the latest code from the `master` branch on the GitHub repo. Then we merge that code into our `pr12` branch.

Remember: `git fetch origin` updates our local `origin/master` to be the same as GitHub's `master`, but it doesn't touch the local branch called simply `master`. We'd have to checkout our `master` branch to make changes to it. Instead, we just update our idea of what's on GitHub (`origin/master`) and merge that into our `pr12`.

When you run the `merge` command, you'll see conflicts. Those represent decisions that git (and GitHub) couldn't make automatically. Edit those files so they're the way you want them to end up. Then:

```
$ git add each/file.txt that/had/conflicts.conf
$ git commit   # Your editor will open with a pre-filled
               # commit message. Just save and close the file.
$ git push origin pr12
```

That is, we add the versions of the files that we fixed, then finish the merge commit we started with `git merge`. Lastly, we push the branch with the new merge commit up to GitHub.

Since we've resolved the conflicts, this branch should be trivial to merge the other way, into `master`. GitHub will notice that, and give you a green "Merge" button.

Comment: After I did git merge origin/master pretty much every file says "both added" and "new file".

Comment: That's odd. Git's telling you that, since the point it time where `origin/master` and `pr12` diverged, both branches have added those files. You can find where they diverged visually using `git log --graph --oneline origin/master pr12`. Does the output of that command look like what you expect the history of those two branches to look like?

Comment: So I've somewhat got it. But now everything from the original repo which got merged with the forked repo appears in the branch. And when I try to revert that one commit, it says something about the -m switch.

Comment: By "repo" here, do you mean "branch"? You want everything from the original (`master`) branch to be in `pr12`. That means it's up to date. (The error about the `-m` switch is because you're trying to revert a merge commit and go back to its parent, but merge commits have multiple parents: the commits you merged together. The `-m` switch lets you pick which one you want to revert to.)

Answer (score 10):

When I encountered this message, it was because my *fork* of a particular repo was behind the original. In my particular case the repo I'd forked is `pydata/pandas`.

I had to [configure a remote for my fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) by doing:

```
> git remote add upstream git@github.com:original_user/original_repo.git
> git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:some_user/pandas.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:some_user/pandas.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:pydata/pandas.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:pydata/pandas.git (push)
```

*(Note: `git remote add upstream` is a git's way of saying "Add a remote called "upstream". The name can be anything.)*

Then I [fetched the latest commits](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) from the original repo with:

```
> git fetch upstream
> git checkout master # Just in case you're not already on master
> git merge upstream/master
```

and finally push the merged repo back to github:

```
> git push
```

Comment: Thanks! I've searching for a while and this resolves my problem