# I cannot see the conflicts that github is alerting me of

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

When revising a pull request (it is: https://github.com/iluaepidi/widget/pull/8 but I don't know if that data is important) I read this message on github:

> This branch has conflicts that must be resolved
>   use the command line to resolve conflicts before continuing.

But then following the instructions given I cannot see those conflicts. Here my steps with comments:

> Step 1: From your project repository, check out a new branch and test
>   the changes.

```
git checkout -b p-sl-Reply-comments master
git pull https://github.com/p-sl/widget.git Reply-comments
```

(both done with no surprises)

> Step 2: Merge the changes and update on GitHub.

```
OFFICIAL: git checkout master
```

(foreseeing the conflicts here, I made a new branch called 'conflictos')

```
git checkout -B conflictos master
```

(I got sure that both branches had the same code)

```
git diff conflictos..master
```

(returned empty)

```
OFFICIAL:  git merge --no-ff p-sl-Reply-comments
```

(then mi command was the same but executed from conflictos rather than master)
It returned a normal message:

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 css/widgetfeedback_ul.css | 27 +++++++++++---
 src/js/widget.js          | 90 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----
 ul-new-interface.html     | 53 ++++++++++++++--------------
 3 files changed, 131 insertions(+), 39 deletions(-)

OFFICIAL: git push origin master
```

(I haven't done this since I was expecting having to make some changes)

I think I would receive some messages about the conflicts (as seen e.g. on https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/). I even opened those three files to look for the typical lines <<<< ==== >>>> but I couldn't find them.

Another questions here (e.g. ["This pull request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241428/this-pull-request-contains-merge-conflicts-that-must-be-resolved/32334659)) tell me about the conflicts I will see. This simply doesn't happen on my case

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did all the official steps (against master branch, including the push) and github doesn't complain anymore! what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're merging with *your fork*'s master branch.  But your pull request is requesting that your branch be merged with your *upstream*'s master branch (the `master` branch of `iluaepidi/widget`).

You need to merge with that branch to resolve conflicts.

When I work on an Open Source project that I have forked, [I set up a new Git remote called `upstream` to point to the upstream project](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/iluaepidi/widget
```

Then I fetch the branches from my upstream:

```
git fetch upstream
```

And finally, you can now merge the master branch into your branch:

```
git checkout Reply-comments
git merge upstream/master
```

(The [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) is helpful here.)